# Can't download Azure PublishSettings file for another subscription

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azureportal

I try to manage my customer's subscription from PowerShell, but I can't download it's publish settings file.

If I try from Visual Studio I have this error.

[image: Error with azure subscriptions]

My role on my customer's subscription is Owner. Am I missing something so I can download the settings file?

Comment: Can you access this subscription in azure portal?

Comment: Yes, I can add / remove resources without any problem

Answer (score 2):

Just follow https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings link, then login to your subscription and `*.publishsettings` file will be generated automatically.

Comment: This does not work, it only generates the certificate for my subscription. I need it for my customer's subscription.

Comment: Do you have different accounts for these subscriptions?

Comment: My customer's one and mine

Comment: How can you login to customer's account and receive settings for your account? Probably I completely miss something, sorry :( Anyway I would  logout and then login again or try different browser.

Comment: This link brings me to the home page of Azure and I can't find the publishSettings.

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround is to first set the subscription you need as your active subscription and only then to go and download the publish settings

Comment: How do you select an active subscription?

Comment: Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId <subscription id>

Comment: I can't download my customer's publish setttings file.